# Codeigniter class inheritance. Autoload libraries

Tags: codeigniter

Main class inherits from the class CI_Controller and contains another class (and its object), which also inherits from the class CI_Controller. The problem is that my libraries are automatically loaded (config / autoload.php) to both controllers, which returns an error.

How to create a CI instance in the class in the folder 'controllers'? Class is not inherited CI_Controllers and does not work  get_instance function ().

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `MY_Controller` class that extends the normal `CI_Controller`.
The framework will autoload your class (not sure - it's been a while I used CI) alternatively you may need to add the class name in the `autoload.php` file.

After that, Extend your main class using `My_Controller`.